# Checking if a set is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Whenever there's a set $S$ which is a vector space, I keep on hearing in lectures that "$S$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication, so it is a vector space". I don't understand why. Perhaps when $S$ is a subspace of a larger vector space, many of the vector space axioms carry over to $S$, but when that's not the case, can anyone explain why "$S$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication, so it is a vector space"? Do those two conditions guarantee all the vector space axioms?

Comment: All the axioms need to be checked for an arbitrary space.

Comment: @Jamāl So are those conditions not sufficient to guarantee that something is a vector space? Are there any specific instances (apart from subspaces) or criterion in which those two conditions are sufficient to guarantee that something is a vector space?

Comment: Yeah they're not sufficient. Properties like commutativity over addition need not hold for abstract structures.

Comment: You'd need a criterion strong enough to cover the remaining axioms. Perhaps there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full list of requirements are [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition). The vectors must form an Abelian group under addition, they must be closed under multiplication by all scalars in some field, and with such multiplication scalars $a,\,b$ and vectors $u,\,v$ must satisfy$$(ab)v=a(bv),\,1v=v,\,(a+b)u=au+bu,\,a(u+v)=au+av.$$

Answer (score 1):

No.  What you are referring to is purely the *subspace* criterion.

Of course every vector space is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.  But the "converse" is not true.